# Convert string to Array or List in Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I am using Soap UI to test the RESTFul webservices.. 
I have stored [1,2,3,4,5....,10] in the property as PassedValue.. i have to convert this value as Array or list..so that i can fetch each index value.

```
ExpectedValue = context.testCase.getPropertyValue("PassedValue") as String[]
```

This is not working.. if I Print ExpectedValue[0] it prints "["

I wanted to extract ExpectedValue[0] as 1 and 1st index as 2.. .

tried to convert as .toList but still no luck..

Can any one help me out on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **Eval**

For instance;

```
def expectedValue = Eval.me(context.testCase.getPropertyValue("PassedValue"))
```

For More Information [Eval Class](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html)

Answer (score 1):

I liked *@Gokhan's* solution but am putting this as alternative solution.

You can use `JsonSlurper` to achieve the same thing:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def result = ​new JsonSlurper().parseText("[1,2,3]")
```

​